# Datasource order changed while sorting and grouping in server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have tried asp sorting and grouping the datasource the order will be changed. But in client side working fine. We have attached code snippet below.

```
List<accs> acc = new List<accs>();

acc.Add(new accs() { Account = "4320", Content = "Invest" });
acc.Add(new accs() { Account = "4290", Content = "rewrw" });
acc.Add(new accs() { Account = "4290", Content = "test11" });

var list = acc.OrderBy(x => x.Content);

var t = list.GroupBy(p => p.Account, p => p.Content, (key, g) => new { Account = key, Content = g.ToList() });

return View();
```

serverside output:

0-Account="4320"

1-Account="4290"

ClientSide output:

0-Account="4290"

1-Account="4320"

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Regards,

Gopi G.